# C language File io

Tags: c, file, io

I am trying to read a file in C language

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
      char *pathname = "Dictionary_korean.txt";
      if(access(pathname, R_OK) == 0)
    puts("It's OK to read");
   else
    puts("no authority");
}
```

I wrote ths code to see that if this .txt file is not able to read.
but the result of this code was 'It's OK to read'.
so I wrote a another code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void){
char str[100];
char ch;
FILE * src = fopen("Dictionary_korean.txt", "rt");

if(src == NULL || des == NULL){
    puts("Failed to open the FILE");
    return -1;
}

fgets(str, sizeof(str), src);
printf("%s", str);
fgets(str, sizeof(str), src);
printf("%s", str);

fclose(src);

return 0;
 }
```

this is the second code. In this code, the result has to be the 2 strings in the 'Dictionary_korean.txt' File, but it only prints '?'

so I thought that my program had had an error.
so, I copied the 'Dictionary_korean.txt' file to 'BBB.txt' File and made a same code depending on the 'BBB.txt', and it worked properly.

I also checked the authority of the 'Dictionary_korean.txt' Note pad file, but it had all of the authority it can have.

what do you think the problem is?

Comment: The problem is that `Dictionary_korean.txt` probably isn't ASCII encoded

Comment: What is `des`? Please post a full [mcve]

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry Tim.
des is the variable that I made it to test the code.
In the upper code, des is nothing.
I think that's the one reason of the error
Thanks!

StoryTeller, then how can I solve the problem?
How can I encode the txt file??